# Watched tags not displaying

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

As you can clearly see [organic-chemistry] is a tag that I have been watching. However the first question in the image doesn't show up as watched. This behavior is not seen on Meta SE but seen on all other sites which is confusing. Does anyone else have the same problem?

I use Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77.

Comment: On a different note: Why do you watch [tag:homework]? It has been deprecated.

Comment: Exactly for that reason so I can edit it out if somebody uses it in their post.

Comment: But nobody uses it. The tag info for it is "DEPRECATED. DON'T USE THIS TAG" thus making sure that no one uses it.

Comment: @NilayGhosh, It's a just a redundancy. *If* someone does use it, I can atleast know. This doesn't mean a lot of people do, but you would be surprised in knowing that questions have popped up. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/151483/revisions

Comment: @NilayGhosh You would be surprised how many still use it; even when you shout it in their monitors. Spring cleaning also watches the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [post on MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken), the issue has been discovered and a solution is enroute. From Marc Gravell, an SE staff member,

> Sorry about that. What happened here: the favorites/ignored feature is implemented client-side; a UI tweak changed the DOM in a way that broke the jQuery selector, meaning that it no longer found the tag data. I've put a PR together that fixes this - we'll get it deployed as soon as we can (after validation, etc).